# Weird inexact error in julia

Tags: julia

I have two instances of my program tracked with git, so I know that they are in sync. One instance is in machine A and the other in machine B.

Machine A runs fine, but when I go to machine B I obtain the following error:

```
ERROR: InexactError()
in setindex! at array.jl:307
in setindex! at array.jl:345
in main at /path/to/main.jl:122
in include at ./boot.jl:246
in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:128
in process_options at ./client.jl:285
in _start at ./client.jl:354
in _start_3B_3587 at /home/usr/julia/usr/bin/../lib/julia/sys.so
while loading /path/to/main.jl, in expression starting on line 265
```

I don't understand why it throws and error. Both machines have the last master version of Julia:

```
Version 0.4.0-dev+3322 (2015-02-12 13:56 UTC)
Commit 1ec68b3* (0 days old master)
```

The lines that throw the error are

```
array2 = zeros(Float64,NHn*2000)
for iRealiz in 1:2000
    ...
    ij = (iRealiz-1)*NHn
    egvals_ts, egvecs_ts = eig(timeser)
    array2[ij+1:ij+NHn] = egvals_ts
    ...
end
```

NHn is the matrix dimension.

Comment: done it, added HEAD status.

Comment: And what's the code that causes the problem?

Comment: It's more fun than that, I decided to update julia in both machines (git pull && make).
A is compilling... B says (after a make clean)

`  $make
/bin/sh: line 1: cmake: command not found
make[2]: *** [libgit2-0.22.0/build/Makefile] Error 127
make[1]: *** [julia-release] Error 2
make: *** [release] Error 2`

Comment: We recommend using a stable (currently 0.3) release. The master (0.4) branch is changing fairly rapidly as you've noticed.

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error, `in main at /path/to/main.jl:122`

Comment: The line that boils up is

array2[ij+1:ij+NHn] = egvals

where egvals are the eigenvalues of a NxN matrix. array2 is a collection of different realizations of the NxN matrix.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `Inexact Error` gets thrown when you try to convert a value `x` to a type `T` that cannot represent the value of `x`. For example, on julia 0.4:

```
julia> convert(Int, 3.0)
3

julia> convert(Int, 3.2)
ERROR: InexactError()
 in convert at int.jl:189

julia> convert(UInt, -2)
ERROR: InexactError()
```

and finally, in what is likely relevant for your case:

```
julia> convert(Float64, 2+0.3im)
ERROR: InexactError()
 in convert at complex.jl:16
```

My theory is that roundoff errors (which are dependent on the particular CPU) caused it to return complex-valued eigenvalues on one machine but not the other.

Comment: You're totally right, I get complex eigenvalues from the diagonalization. The weird thing is that the version A of my program do not report the errors, while version B it does.

Maybe this is related with the so known "Wilkinson Eigenvalue problem". http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Eigenvalue-Monographs-Numerical-Analysis/dp/0198534183 (if you have the original paper, be free to share it).